# How can I get the exact value of a double?

Tags: c++, c++11, double, rounding, gcc5.2

I have a situation where:

```
void foo( const double d )
{
    const double rounded_2_decimals = std::round(d*100.0) / 100.0;
    std::cout << "d=" << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r=" << rounded_2_decimals << std::endl;
}
```

When printed, `d=3.125`, but `r=3.12` instead of `r=3.13`.

I suspect that is because the passed in `d` is actually 3.1249999....  This is why I put in the initial cout, so I could see the "true" value being passed in.  Does `std::cout` round values before it displays them?  How else could I see the "real" value being passed in?

Comment: My bad, `round` always rounds away from zero. Use `std::setprecision`, or print as hexfloat.

Comment: Isn't the definition of std::round() to round away from zero?  Is there a way to change the "rounding mode"?

Comment: You're right (I misread the question as `foo(3.125)` printing 3.12), and then didn't lookup `std::round` because the only plausible explanation for that behavior is rounding half to even)

Comment: Anyone know where it might be documented that std::cout rounds numbers before displaying them?  I'd like to understand the exact rules.

Comment: Turns out my guess was right. When using `std::precision(25)` I noticed the number was indeed just a hair smaller than the .5 rounding limit:  3.1249999999999995559107901.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `std::cout` does round values, however you can set a higher precision. First include the `iomanip` header. Then:

```
void foo( const double d )
{
    const double rounded_2_decimals = std::round(d*100.0) / 100.0;
    std::cout << "d=" << std::setprecision(9) <<  d << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r=" << std::setprecision(9) << rounded_2_decimals << std::endl;
}
```

Live example program [here](http://ideone.com/D8e8Aw)

Comment: The trick was to use std::setprecision(9) in combination with std::fixed.

Comment: `std::fixed` isn't necessary to get the "real" value, as `std::precision` suffices in providing higher precision that specifies the max digits covering both sides of the decimal point. The result ignores trailing zeros that are less than the max digits specified. However, if you want specific formatting such as a fixed number of digits after the decimal point, or want to specify the precision for the number of digits after the decimal point, then yes, you can combine it with `std::fixed`

Comment: Thanks, ccoder83. The truncation of the trailing zeros led me down the wrong path. Increasing the value in `std::setprecision()` eventually showed me what I suspected, that the value was just a hair smaller than the .5 necessary to round up.

Comment: @Stéphane it may take up to 53 digits to see the entire value if it's between 1.0 and 2.0, more if it's less than 1.0.